# Persistent communication in MPI - odd behaviour

Tags: mpi, nonblocking

I am solving the *coarsest grid* of *parallel geometric* multi grid using *jacobi* iterations and using Non-blocking calls `MPI_Isend()` and `MPI_Irecv()`. There are no problems in this. As soon as I replace the non-blocking communications with `persistent communications` - the results stop converging at this level and program goes into an infinite loop. The calls `MPI_Startall()` and `MPI_Waitall()` always return `MPI_SUCCESS`. Has anyone faced this problem before ? Please advise.

```
 Coarsest_grid_solve()
{
MPI_Recv_init(&e_c_old[0][1][1], 1, x_subarray_c, X_DOWN, 10, new_comm, &recv[0]);
MPI_Recv_init(&e_c_old[PXC+1][1][1], 1, x_subarray_c, X_UP, 20, new_comm, &recv[1]);
MPI_Recv_init(&e_c_old[1][PYC+1][1], 1, y_subarray_c, Y_RIGHT, 30, new_comm, &recv[2]);
MPI_Recv_init(&e_c_old[1][0][1], 1, y_subarray_c, Y_LEFT, 40, new_comm, &recv[3]); 
MPI_Recv_init(&e_c_old[1][1][PZC+1], 1, z_subarray_c, Z_AWAY_U, 50, new_comm, &recv[4]);
MPI_Recv_init(&e_c_old[1][1][0], 1, z_subarray_c, Z_TOWARDS_U, 60, new_comm, &recv[5]);

MPI_Send_init(&e_c_old[PXC][1][1], 1, x_subarray_c, X_UP, 10, new_comm, &send[0]);
MPI_Send_init(&e_c_old[1][1][1], 1, x_subarray_c, X_DOWN, 20, new_comm, &send[1]);
MPI_Send_init(&e_c_old[1][1][1], 1, y_subarray_c, Y_LEFT, 30, new_comm, &send[2]);
MPI_Send_init(&e_c_old[1][PYC][1], 1, y_subarray_c, Y_RIGHT, 40, new_comm, &send[3]);
MPI_Send_init(&e_c_old[1][1][1], 1, z_subarray_c, Z_TOWARDS_U, 50, new_comm, &send[4]);
MPI_Send_init(&e_c_old[1][1][PZC], 1, z_subarray_c, Z_AWAY_U, 60, new_comm, &send[5]);  

while(rk_global/r0_global > TOL_CNORM)              
{
coarse_iterations++ ;           

err = MPI_Startall(6,recv);
if(err == MPI_SUCCESS)
    printf("success");

err = MPI_Startall(6,send);
if(err == MPI_SUCCESS)
    printf("success");

err = MPI_Waitall(6, send, MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE);
if(err == MPI_SUCCESS)
    printf("success");

err = MPI_Waitall(6, recv, MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE);
if(err == MPI_SUCCESS)
    printf("success");

//do work here

if(coarse_iterations == 1)
{
    update_neumann_c(e_c_old, PXC, PYC, PZC, X_UP, Y_RIGHT, Z_AWAY_U);
    residual_coarsest(e_c_old, rho_c, PXC, PYC, PZC, X_UP, Y_RIGHT, Z_AWAY_U, hc, rho_temp); 
    r0_local = residual_norm(rho_temp, PXC, PYC, PZC); 
    start_allred = MPI_Wtime();
    MPI_Allreduce(&r0_local, &r0_global, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_SUM, new_comm); 
    end_allred = MPI_Wtime(); 
    r0_global = r0_global/( (PXC*dims0) * (PYC*dims1) * (PZC*dims2) ); 
    if(rank == 0)
        printf("\nGlobal residual norm is = %f", r0_global);
    rk_global = r0_global;
}           
else
{
    update_neumann_c(e_c_old, PXC, PYC, PZC, X_UP, Y_RIGHT, Z_AWAY_U);
    residual_coarsest(e_c_old, rho_c, PXC, PYC, PZC, X_UP, Y_RIGHT, Z_AWAY_U, hc, rho_temp); 
    rk_local = residual_norm(rho_temp, PXC, PYC, PZC);
    start_allred = MPI_Wtime(); 
    MPI_Allreduce(&rk_local, &rk_global, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_SUM, new_comm);
    end_allred = MPI_Wtime();  
    rk_global = rk_global/( (PXC*dims0) * (PYC*dims1) * (PZC*dims2) );
    if(rank == 0)
        printf("\nGlobal residual norm is = %f", rk_global);
}

//do dependent work and exchange matrices
}//while loop ends

for(i = 0; i <= 5 ; i++)
{
    MPI_Request_free(&send[i]);
    MPI_Request_free(&recv[i]);
}
}//End coarsest grid solve
```

*Note*: Strangely the ghost data becomes zero on alternate iterations. (Just found out - don't know why).

Comment: Apologies - just edited and added relevant code.

Comment: I think it is because I am carrying out Jacobi iterations and exchanging pointers at the end to point to different matrices - it only passes data when the pointer points to the original matrix.

Answer (score 2):

When we make a persistent handle for communication, we point to a specific piece of memory that we want to transfer to some other process. Now in Jacobi iterations we need to exchange pointers at the end of the iteration to make the *old* matrix point to the *new* updated matrix. Thus, the memory location pointed to by the pointer changes. Thus, the original locations are exchanged. The way around is to define *two* persistent communication handles. On odd iterations use the first handle and on even iterations use the other handle i.e. alternate them. This solved my problem. This problem also widened my understanding of persistent communications in MPI.

Comment: Yes, the buffer argument to `MPI_Yyy_init` gets remembered my MPI and then the same buffer is used for all consequently started communications. It's good that you've learned it on your own. An advice - when posting questions in the future, try to first distil your problem into a small fully-functional example code that still reproduces the problem and can be compiled and tested by the members of SO. Usually, you will find the solution on your own while doing so, and if not, you will make the life of those who try to answer your question easier.

Comment: Many thanks for confirming and the advice. I will follow it from now.